# If X is a nonempty open set, then X is uncountable

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove that if $X$ is a nonempty open set, then $X$ is uncountable.

Any input as to how I could prove this would be appreciated. I was thinking of doing a contrapositive proof. Where I say assume $X$ is countable and go on to show that $X$ is a nonempty closed set. Is there a better more concise way to prove this?

Comment: Not true. You have to say open set in what space. Are you considering open sets in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: In what topology?

Comment: Take any countable (nonempty) set $X$, then under any topology on $X$ it must be the case that $X$ is open.

Comment: Are all open sets a subset of the Reals?

Comment: @user3753 No.  The Reals with the standard  topology are only one example of a _topological space_.

Comment: OK, the question should be made more precise, but the tag *real-analysis* leaves little doubt about the topology and the space considered by the OP.

Comment: The question I am considering says nothing about it being an open set on the reals. I have fixed the tags. No space is mention just in general "If  X is a nonempty open set, then X is countable.

Comment: @user3753 Elementary set theory says nothing about open sets.  This is a topology question.

Comment: What you just wrote contradicts your title. But in any case, the statement is false in the abstract: there are topological spaces that are *finite*, in which all open sets are finite. And given any set $X$ with more than $1$ elements, if you let $A$ be a proper nonempty subset of $X$, then $\{\varnothing, A, X\}$ is a topology on $X$, and if $X$ is infinite, you can pick $A$ to be either finite or countable at your pleasure.

Comment: @user3753 You should have left the tag *real-analysis*. Now, as the other comments show, your question is plain wrong. Take any nonempty finite set with the discrete topology.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the reals, the standard topology is generated by the intervals $(a,b)$.  It is well-known that any such interval is uncountable (one way of seeing this is that $(a,b)\cong\Bbb R$). The result follows.

For a general topological space this is false.

Answer (score 2):

If a set, even the reals, is given the discrete topology, then all subsets are open. In particular, that means that even sets with one element are open. As Chris Custer points out, if  the reals are given the usual topology, then open sets are uncountable. It's not just the set that is important, but what topology it carries.

Comment: _Nonempty_ open sets...

Comment: @Chris Custer - Yes. That was careless of me.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false in general (take the [discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) on any set - you will get get open singletons there).

However your statement is true for [normed vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) equipped with natural topology:

Suppose $(E, ||.||)$ is a normed vector space. Suppose, $X$ is a nonempty open subset of $E$ in natural topology and $x \in X$. Then, by definition of natural topology on a normed space, $\exists \epsilon > 0$, such that $\{v \in E: ||x - v|| < \epsilon\} \subset X$. However, one can also see, that $(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{||x||};1 + \frac{\epsilon}{||x||})x \subset \{v \in E: ||x - v|| < \epsilon\}$ and it is obviously uncountable.